# Project Euler p14 enhance performance

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

I have completed project Euler problem 14 with the following code:

```
def longest_Collatz_sequence():
    """
    returns longest Collatz
    sequence based on formula:
    n --> n/2 (n is even)
    n --> 3n + 1 (n is odd)
    """
    bestSequence = []
    lengthOfLongest = 0
    longestSequence = []
    for n in range(999999,1,-1):
        while n != 1:
            l = len(longestSequence)
            if n % 2 == 0:
                longestSequence.append(n)
                n /= 2
            elif n % 2 != 0:
                longestSequence.append(n)
                n = (n * 3) + 1
            if longestSequence[-1] == 2 and lengthOfLongest < l:  
                lengthOfLongest = l
                bestSequence = longestSequence[:]
                bestSequence.append(1)       
        longestSequence = []
    return bestSequence[0]
```

It takes around 39 seconds to get the longest Collatz
 sequence of numbers from 1000000 down to 2.
I would like to know if I could be caching any values to speed up my code, also how to 
remove  if longestSequence[-1] == 2 from my code without getting an infinite loop and any other ways the code can be improved.

The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive integers:

n → n/2 (n is even)
n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)

Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following sequence:

13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1
It can be seen that this sequence (starting at 13 and finishing at 1) contains 10 terms. Although it has not been proved yet (Collatz Problem), it is thought that all starting numbers finish at 1.

Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?

NOTE: Once the chain starts the terms are allowed to go above one million.

Comment: The first thing you'll want to do is separate out the Collatz sequence length logic into its own function. Then it will be easier to cache.

Comment: @fritzone whenever I google to learn about the algorithms used in any Euler project, I am bombarded with Project Euler solutions so unless a Euler has no knowledge of google or how to use any search engine then I really don't see how my question, amongst  a sea of others  will have any bearing on anybody else doing the problem.

Comment: @fritzone Project Euler questions are on topic for the site as homework questions are. People who come across this problem will not be spoiled because 1) it's really easy to just not look at the answer, and 2) since Project Euler is a “homework” question the answers tend to be only partially complete.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Do you mean, put the   n --> n/2 (n is even)
    n --> 3n + 1 (n is odd) in a function of its own and cache the results of that? Sorry I am pretty inexperienced so it takes a bit for me to fully understand sometimes

Comment: I mean to say that your main function should be as simple as `print(max(collatz(i) for i in range(1000000)))`. You should then design `collatz(n)` so that it returns the Collatz sequence length for `n`. Then you can add memoization to the workings of `collatz`.

Comment: Hi. I thought it was the Collatz *conjecture*. The sequence being called the hailstone sequence.

See the Rosetta Code page references for more info: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hailstone_sequence

Comment: @Paddy3118 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Hi, your link states ... "the sequence of numbers involved is referred to as the hailstone sequence or hailstone numbers (because the values are usually subject to multiple descents and ascents like hailstones in a cloud)". Collatz *is* the conjecture not the name of the series.

Comment: @Paddy3118 I googled Collatz Problem when I encountered the question and I got the formula from the results so that is the limit of my knowledge of the Collatz Problem.

Comment: see this java implementation https://interviewquizandanswers.blogspot.com/2020/04/project-euler-14-longest-collatz.html

Answer (score 2):

Each time you generate an item in the sequence, you are also generating the items for *that* item. For example, for 13, you find that it produces 10 items.  But in the process you also find out that 40 produces 9 items, 20 produces 8 items, 10 produces 7 items, etc. You can remember that information in a list or dictionary, so that after doing 13, you never have to look at 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 4, or 2.

Furthermore, when you generate a sequence you haven't seen before, you can look at this information and use it as a shortcut. For 13, you would already have seen 10 before seeing 13, so you just calculate 40, 20, 10 and then you know 10 produces 7 items so you just add that to the 3 you've already seen and don't bother calculating the rest.

This will use a fair bit of memory but it's totally doable for the number of items you have to consider. You could have some kind of cutoff (for example, only store results for numbers 100,000 or under) which would still achieve a great speed improvement but use less memory.

An easy-ish way to do this is to rewrite your function to calculate the sequence recursively instead of iteratively, and then apply a memoization decorator such as [this one](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578231-probably-the-fastest-memoization-decorator-in-the-/). There is some overhead in the recursion, but the benefit of memoization will probably outweigh that.

Comment: Thanks, I have done a little memoization when I did the MIT 6.00x python course a while back but still a little hazy on how to use it with a function but I will give both your suggestions a try and see which works best.